# How to Automate Code Compilation with different flag combinations through a Single Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile

Suppose I am having a Makefile with the following flags:

```
CFLAGS+=FLAG1
.............
CFLAGS+=FLAG2
.............
CFLAGS+=FLAG3
.............
CFLAGS+=FLAG4
.............
CFLAGS+=FLAG5
```

Can someone please give some hint on how to automate the Compilation with different flag combinations through this Makefile & saving the errors & Flag Combination details in different error logs.

Example:

```
Error log for a particular Flag Combination:

Combination: FLAG1 FLAG3 FLAG5
errors       ................. (may be blank as well).
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is *much* easier to implement in shell (`sh`) than in make. Is there any reason why it shouldn't be done in shell?

Comment: When you run Make, do you want to specify a single combination of flags, or a set, or iterate through all possible combinations?

Comment: @Beta: Yes, I want to iterate through all possible combinations. Is there any way?

Comment: And for each combination you want to build some binary files, an error log and a log of the flags? And you want the different combinations not to overwrite each other's products? Do you have a preference about the directory structure?

Comment: @Beta: Thanks for your reply. I exactly want what you have stated above. Regarding the directory structure, I have to export some directory paths - needed for compilation, but these paths are Absolute paths (not relative paths) and they point to the obj files needed for compiling the current directory. Can you please give me some hint?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up an output directory for each flag combination. So you have to:

- Create a makefile that will define the actual rules. The output files have to be placed in different directory than sources. You have two options to achieve that, either

  - use appropriate configurable prefixes to all paths or
  - use `VPATH` variable (than current directory is output and sources are searched in `VPATH`).
- Create a makefile with appropriate setting for each directory, that will include the rules.

Than you have two options how to dispatch the make:

1. Run each build separately, possibly having top-level makefile that will run each build as separate process (recursively), or
2. define the rules with [target-specific variable values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) and include them all from the top-level makefile. This will also require the rules to only be for files in particular directory, so you can't use `VPATH` and you'll need to either use patterns like `$(out_dir)/%.o : %.c`, or you need to use [static-pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) which explicitly list the targets they apply to.