# Handling all symbols combinations in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

Say I have designed a C++ library, and I want to extensively test all the features.
Some of these features are defined at build-time, through symbols that are defined or not.

```
// library.h
A foo( const B& b )
{
#ifdef OPTION_X
   ... do it that way
#else
   ... do it another way
#endif
}
```

I build a test program that I want to build and run for all possible configurations, to make sure all tests pass:

```
// mytest.cpp
#include "library.h"
int main()
{
    ... some test code
#ifdef OPTION_X
    ... do it that way
#else
   ... do it that other way
#endif
    ... more stuff with more options
}
```

If I have 1 option (call it "A"), I want to run the tests if it is "on"
(`_AY` for option "A": Yes) or "off" (`_AN` for option "A": No)

My makefile holds this:

```
.PHONY: test

test: BUILD/mytest_AY BUILD/mytest_AN
    BUILD/mytest_AY
    BUILD/mytest_AN

BUILD/mytest_AY: CXXFLAGS+=-DOPTION_A

BUILD/mytest_AY: mytest.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

BUILD/mytest_AN: mytest.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)
```

This is fine.

But now, if I have 2 options to test (say "A" and "B"), you see the point:
I will have 4 targets to build and run:

```
test: BUILD/mytest_AYBY BUILD/mytest_ANBY BUILD/mytest_AYBN BUILD/mytest_ANBN
    BUILD/mytest_AYBY
    BUILD/mytest_ANBY
    BUILD/mytest_AYBN
    BUILD/mytest_ANBN

BUILD/mytest_AYBN: CXXFLAGS+=-DOPTION_A
BUILD/mytest_AYBY: CXXFLAGS+="-DOPTION_A -DOPTION_B"
BUILD/mytest_ANBY: CXXFLAGS+=-DOPTION_B

BUILD/mytest_AYBY: mytest.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

BUILD/mytest_ANBY: mytest.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

BUILD/mytest_AYBN: mytest.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

BUILD/mytest_ANBN: mytest.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)
```

I have two questions:

- is there a way to have a single rule/recipe instead of the four?
  There are all the same, except for the target name.
- this approach, while ok for 1 or 2 build-time options, does not scale well.
  3 would already be pretty much cumbersome, more, it becomes a nightmare.
  How would you handle that situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238188/automatically-build-binaries-for-all-combinations-of-preprocessor-defines

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877804/how-to-automate-code-compilation-with-different-flag-combinations-through-a-sing

Comment: @user202729 Ah, thanks, did miss that one when I searched. i'll take a look.

Comment: Ok, from the linked questions, seems that I got the trick for my first question. I'll check.

Comment: But I'd really like an answer to the second question. I'm sure I'm not the only one that ran into that issue.

Comment: One solution (comment) there suggest using bash. (well there's no reason why you can't use bash, right? Besides why not Python/C++/perl/whatever-can-generate-makefiles)

Comment: @user202729 Sure, bash is fine, and indeed, I'm starting to think that make can't be the solution to everything... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem. If you have GNU make you can try something like the following. The compilation and execution commands are just echoed; remove the two `echo` and the `@` silencers when you will be satisfied with what you see. There are 3 options: `A`, `B` and `C`; add more if you wish or specify them on the command line with `make test ONAMES="A B C D E F"`.

```
# option names
ONAMES   := A B C
# number of options
ONUM     := $(words $(ONAMES))
# configuration binary strings (e.g., 000 001 ... 111)
CONFIGS  := $(shell echo "obase=2; for(i=0; i<2^$(ONUM); i++) 2^$(ONUM)+i" | \
                    bc | sed 's/1//')
# one space
SPACE    := $(NULL) $(NULL)
# list of all test binaries
TESTBINS :=

# the macro used to instantiate a test
# $(1): the configuration binary string (e.g. 101)
define TEST_macro
# the configuration list in NAMEY/N format (e.g., AY BN CY)
config-$(1)  := $$(join $(ONAMES),$$(subst 1,Y ,$$(subst 0,N ,$(1))))
# the test binary (e.g., BUILD/mytest_AYBNCY)
test-$(1)    := BUILD/mytest_$$(subst $$(SPACE),,$$(config-$(1)))
# the list of active options (e.g., A C)
options-$(1) := $$(subst Y,,$$(filter %Y,$$(config-$(1))))
# add the test binary to list of all test binaries
TESTBINS     += $$(test-$(1))

# target-specific compilation options
$$(test-$(1)): CXXFLAGS += $$(addprefix -DOPTION_,$$(options-$(1)))
endef
# apply macro on each configuration binary string
$(foreach c,$(CONFIGS),$(eval $(call TEST_macro,$(c))))

# one phony target per test run (e.g., BUILD/mytest_AYBNCY.run)
TESTRUNS := $(addsuffix .run,$(TESTBINS))
.PHONY: $(TESTRUNS)

# one phony target for all test runs
.PHONY: test
test: $(TESTRUNS)

# static pattern rule for the test runs
$(TESTRUNS): %.run: %
    @echo "./$<"

# rule for the test binaries
$(TESTBINS): mytest.cpp
    @echo "$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)"
```

Demo:

```sh
$ make test
g++ -o BUILD/mytest_ANBNCN mytest.cpp
g++ -DOPTION_C -o BUILD/mytest_ANBNCY mytest.cpp
g++ -DOPTION_B -o BUILD/mytest_ANBYCN mytest.cpp
g++ -DOPTION_B -DOPTION_C -o BUILD/mytest_ANBYCY mytest.cpp
g++ -DOPTION_A -o BUILD/mytest_AYBNCN mytest.cpp
g++ -DOPTION_A -DOPTION_C -o BUILD/mytest_AYBNCY mytest.cpp
g++ -DOPTION_A -DOPTION_B -o BUILD/mytest_AYBYCN mytest.cpp
g++ -DOPTION_A -DOPTION_B -DOPTION_C -o BUILD/mytest_AYBYCY mytest.cpp
./BUILD/mytest_ANBNCN
./BUILD/mytest_ANBNCY
./BUILD/mytest_ANBYCN
./BUILD/mytest_ANBYCY
./BUILD/mytest_AYBNCN
./BUILD/mytest_AYBNCY
./BUILD/mytest_AYBYCN
./BUILD/mytest_AYBYCY
```

Explanations:

We first generate the 2^3=8 binary strings from `000` to `111` with, e.g., `bc` thanks to the `shell` make function. We assign the result to the make variable `CONFIGS`. These binary strings correspond to all possible configurations of the 3 options where a `1` means yes (`Y`) and `0` means no (`N`).

Then, we process each of these configuration strings with the `TEST_macro` macro. This is where the [`foreach-eval-call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) construct enters the picture. With a mixture of `join`, `subst` and other make functions we transform each binary string. For instance, `101` is first transformed into the `AY BN CY` list (variable `config-101`), next into the `BUILD/mytest_AYBNCY` test binary name (variable `test-101`) and next into the `A C` list of enabled options (variable `options-101`). Finally, the list of enabled options is in turn transformed into a target-specific `CXXFLAGS` value with `addprefix`.

> Note: having one separate phony target per test run (e.g., `BUILD/mytest_AYBNCY.run`) is interesting if you have a multi-core computer and you want to run `N` tests in parallel with `make -jN`.

> Note: all this is rather simple except one specific aspect: the macro is expanded twice by make. Once as parameter of the `eval` function and once more when the resulting make construct is re-parsed by make. This is why we use `$$` almost everywhere we would normally find just `$`: to escape the first expansion.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that very detailed and complete answer. I sure will learn some new make tricks here! I need some time to get through it and understand everything.

Comment: A bit overkill for my own usage, but that is a good demonstration of advanced gnumake usage. This answer is very valuable event if I doubt I will use it as such. But the question is indeed throroughly answered.  I feel there could some usage for a tool implementing this in a more "usable" way.

Comment: _A bit overkill_: well, I think I do not know another way to solve your second question with make, except the tedious, error prone and not generic exhaustive listing of configurations. So yes, if you find this overkill, it is probably better to use another tool than make. But remember that make is also doing a lot of important things that the other tool will have to offer too: dependencies, parallel build... CMake or the autotools, for instance, do this by... using make; they are thus not really alternative tools, they are more intermediates between you and make.

Comment: Sure, fully agree. Thanks again for your time, Renaud.